# Create folder with Google Drive SDK iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a folder using the Google Drive SDK for iOS. From the Google Drive documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/folder

It says that creating a folder is just like creating a 'file' with a special MIME type.

```
GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = nil;

self.driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
self.driveFile.title = foldername;

uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters new];
uploadParameters.MIMEType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:self.driveFile
                                    uploadParameters:uploadParameters];


[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                                          NSError *error) {
```

But when I perform the query, I get:

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'upload data and fileHandle are mutually exclusive'

This suggests I should be using one of the predefined GTLUploadParameters factory methods:

```
+ (GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersWithData:(NSData *)data
                                         MIMEType:(NSString *)mimeType;

+ (GTLUploadParameters *)uploadParametersWithFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandle
                                               MIMEType:(NSString *)mimeType;
```

But neither of these are appropriate (or work, as I've tried). Has anyone successfully created folders using Google Drive on iOS?

Answer (score 6):

I do this:

```
    GTLDriveFile *folderObj = [GTLDriveFile object];
    folderObj.title = folderName;
    folderObj.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    // To create a folder in a specific parent folder, specify the identifier
    // of the parent:
    // _resourceId is the identifier from the parent folder
    if (_resourceId.length && ![_resourceId isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
        parentRef.identifier = _resourceId;
        folderObj.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:parentRef];
    }

    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folderObj uploadParameters:nil];

    // executeQuery:...
```

Comment: @rmaddy, can you share your completionBlock?  Are the same parameters passed, e.g. a `GTLDriveFile *`?

Comment: @tarabyte What completion block?

Comment: `completionBlock:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFile *updatedFile,
                                              NSError *error)`?

Comment: @tarabyte Oh, based on your answer you must be talking about the completion block to the call to the `executeQuery` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another more complete variant:

```
+ (void)createFolderWithService:(GTLServiceDrive *)service
                     folderName:(NSString *)folderName
                       parentId:(NSString *)parentId
                completionBlock:(void (^)(GTLServiceTicket *, GTLDriveFile *, NSError *))completionBlock {
  GTLDriveFile *folderObj = [GTLDriveFile object];
  folderObj.title = folderName;
  folderObj.mimeType = @"application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

  if (parentId.length && ![parentId isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    GTLDriveParentReference *parentRef = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
    parentRef.identifier = parentId;
    folderObj.parents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:parentRef];
  }

  GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:folderObj uploadParameters:nil];
  [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:completionBlock];
}
```