# Google Drive exception - upload data and fileHandle are mutually exclusive

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am having a weird bug. I have been uploading a file to Google Drive but suddenly the code stopped working.

Exception info:

> *** Assertion failure in -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher setLocationURL:uploadData:uploadFileHandle:uploadMIMEType:chunkSize:]
>
> Uncaught exception: upload data and fileHandle are mutually exclusive

Detail Code:

```
- (void)googleDriveBackup:(NSString*)path
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =
    [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                          clientID:kClientId
                                                      clientSecret:kClientSecret];
    if ([auth canAuthorize])
    {
        if (path)
        {
            // Upload file to GD
            GTLServiceDrive *driveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];
            driveService.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
            driveService.retryEnabled = YES;
            driveService.authorizer = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                            clientID:kClientId
                                                                                        clientSecret:kClientSecret];
            GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
            query.q = @"'appdata' in parents";
            [driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFileList *files,NSError *error) {
                NSString *fileId = @"";
                GTLDriveFile *updateFile = nil;
                for (GTLDriveFile *file in files.items)
                {
                    if (file.descriptionProperty != nil && [file.descriptionProperty isEqualToString:[self deviceDes]])
                    {
                        fileId = file.identifier;
                        updateFile = file;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] MIMEType:@"application/octet-stream"];
                GTLQueryDrive *query = nil;
                if ([fileId isEqualToString:@""] && updateFile == nil)
                {
                    GTLDriveFile *driveFile = [GTLDriveFile object];
                    driveFile.title = @"GoogleDrive.db";
                    driveFile.originalFilename = @"GoogleDrive.db";
                    driveFile.mimeType = @"application/octet-stream";
                    driveFile.descriptionProperty = [self deviceDes];
                    GTLDriveParentReference *parent = [GTLDriveParentReference object];
                    parent.identifier = @"appdata";
                    driveFile.parents = @[parent];
                    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:driveFile uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
                }
                else
                {
                    query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesUpdateWithObject:updateFile fileId:fileId uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
                }

                [driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {

                    if (error == nil)
                    {
                        CLog(@"Auto_backup Success...");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
                        CLog(@"Auto_backup Failed...");
                    }
                }];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            CLog(@"Auto_backup Failed...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is App cannot locate the folder, double check the folder where the file is being uploaded. Check this Stack overflow ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693238/create-folder-with-google-drive-sdk-ios

Answer (score 0):

The only problem was that the files were not in the path.